# How to destroy session in Kohana using Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, session, kohana, logout

I'm using Facebook login for my site. I'm using Kohana 3.3.1. I have method for logout. When I var_dump($_SESSION) after logout, it's empty array. But problem is that when I've logged out from site and I try to sign in in my site again with another facebook account, it doesn't show Facebook popup for login and I can't sign in with this account. It's still showing data for previous account. And facebook button still has title to sign in, it doesn't show title to logout at all.

How to destroy facebook session completely, so that I should be able to sign in with another facebook account? Thank you in advance!

My login button is this:

```html
<a href="<?php echo URL::base(); ?>membership/logout">Logout</a>
```

Here's my method for login:

```html
public function action_fbLogin(){
      
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'MyAppId',
            'secret' => 'MYSecret',
        ));

        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture')); 
           var_dump($user_profile);
            $user_id = Model_UserFunctions::checkIfUserExist($user_profile['email']); 
            if($user_id > 0)
            {
                
                Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                    'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'first_name' =>  $user_profile['first_name'],
                    'last_name' =>  $user_profile['last_name'],
                ));
                
                //var_dump($_SESSION);
                $this->redirect('profile');
                exit;
            }
            $values = array(
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'username' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'password' => '12345678'
                );
            $user = ORM::factory ( 'User' );
            $user->values($values);
            try
            {
                if($user->save()){
                    $user_new_id = $user->as_array();
                    $user_new_id = $user_new_id['id'];
                    Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                            'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                            'user_id' => $user_new_id,
                            'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                            'email' => $user_profile['email'], 
                            'first_name' => $user_profile['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $user_profile['last_name'],
                        ));
                    
                    $this->redirect('profile');
                }


            }
            catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
            {
                $result = $e->errors('models');
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($result);
                exit;
            }


        }
        else 
        {
            
            $this->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture'))); 
        }
        exit;
    
    }
```

My method for logout is:

```html
public  function action_logout(){
        Session::instance()->delete('user');
       // var_dump($_SESSION);
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: You’ll need to delete the cookies that the SDK has set under your domain as well.

Comment: How to delete them? Could you give me ssome example? Thanks.

Comment: Find out which ones they are (debug output of $_COOKIE) – I think the names include the current user id or something; and then delete them (if you don’t know how to do that with PHP/kohana, go research it.)

Comment: When I var_dump($_COOKIE) I get this: `array(1) { ["G_ENABLED_IDPS"]=> string(6) "google" } ` because I tried Google + login, too. But there isn't facebook cookie. I couldn't find decision to destroy session. I tried this: `$facebook->destroySession();` . There is such method in my module, but there's notice that it's undefined.